# NHibernate "Could not determine type for X" error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

After upgrading the NHibernate and FluentNHibernate DLLs in a project, I'm now getting a "Could not determine type for: MyApp.Domain.Entities.AppCategory" exception thrown when initializing the SessionFactory.  The only change in my code was tweaking the implementation of ForeignKeyConvention to override the `GetKeyName ( Member member, Type type )` abstract method, instead of `GetKeyName ( PropertyInfo property, Type type )`.

The upgraded DLLs were from 1.0.0.593 to 1.1.0.685 for FluentNHibernate, and from 2.1.0.4000 to 2.1.2.4000 for NHibernate.  Part of the difficulty in finding a solution is the old age of the NHibernate version we're using, but that can't be changed, at least for now.

I posted the full exception and all relevant code and configuration below.  I apologize for the length, but I have no idea where the problem might be.

**Full Exception**

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException : An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

  ----> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException : An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

  ----> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: (XmlDocument)
  ----> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not determine type for: MyApp.Domain.Entities.AppCategory, MyApp.Domain, Version=1.0.0.76, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(AppCategory)
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs: line 98
at MyFramework.App.DataAccess.NHibernate.Databases.BaseDatabase.CreateSessionFactory() in C:\WIP\VSProjects\MyFramework\src\App\DataAccess\NHibernate\Databases\BaseDatabase.cs: line 115
at MyFramework.App.DataAccess.NHibernate.Databases.BaseDatabase.Init() in C:\WIP\VSProjects\MyFramework\src\App\DataAccess\NHibernate\Databases\BaseDatabase.cs: line 100
at MyApp.DataAccess.SmartStudioUserUnitOfWork.<.ctor>b__0() in SmartStudioUserUnitOfWork.cs: line 28
at MyFramework.App.DataAccess.NHibernate.UnitOfWork`1.Create(FlushMode flushMode) in C:\WIP\VSProjects\MyFramework\src\App\DataAccess\NHibernate\UnitOfWork.cs: line 72
at MyFramework.App.DataAccess.NHibernate.UnitOfWork`1..ctor(Func`1 getBaseDatabase) in C:\WIP\VSProjects\MyFramework\src\App\DataAccess\NHibernate\UnitOfWork.cs: line 37
at MyApp.DataAccess.SmartStudioUserUnitOfWork..ctor() in SmartStudioUserUnitOfWork.cs: line 17
at MyApp.DataAccess.Test.SmartStudioUserDaoTest.create_dao() in SmartStudioUserDaoTest.cs: line 20
--FluentConfigurationException
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration() in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs: line 119
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs: line 93
--MappingException
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocumentThroughQueue(NamedXmlDocument document)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlReader hbmReader, String name)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument doc, String name)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocument(XmlDocument doc)
at FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.Configure(Configuration cfg) in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\PersistenceModel.cs: line 262
at FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoPersistenceModel.Configure(Configuration configuration) in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Automapping\AutoPersistenceModel.cs: line 170
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.AutoMappingsContainer.Apply(Configuration cfg) in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\AutoMappingsContainer.cs: line 84
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.MappingConfiguration.Apply(Configuration cfg) in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\MappingConfiguration.cs: line 56
at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration() in d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs: line 110
--MappingException
at NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.get_Type()
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassBinder.BindProperty(XmlNode node, Property property, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassBinder.CreateProperty(IValue value, String propertyName, String className, XmlNode subnode, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassBinder.BindJoin(XmlNode node, Join join, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.ClassBinder.PropertiesFromXML(XmlNode node, PersistentClass model, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas, UniqueKey uniqueKey, Boolean mutable, Boolean nullable, Boolean naturalId)
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind(XmlNode node, HbmClass classSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddRootClasses(XmlNode parentNode, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(XmlNode node)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
```

**Fluent Configuration**

```
sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Application>().Conventions
            .Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>()))
    .ExposeConfiguration(new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, false))
    .BuildSessionFactory();

public class CustomForeignKeyConvention : ForeignKeyConvention
{
    protected override string GetKeyName ( Member member, Type type )
    {
        if (member == null)
        {
            return type.Name + "Id";
        }

        return member.Name + "Id";
    }
}
```

**Domain classes**

```
public class Application
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public virtual AppCategory AppCategory { get; set; }
}

public class AppCategory
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

**Database Table Definitions**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FriendlyName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [AppCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Application] WITH CHECK
        ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Application_AppCategory] FOREIGN KEY([AppCategoryId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[AppCategory] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Application] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Application_AppCategory]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppCategory](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AppCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

**Fluent NHibernate Mapping**

```
public class ApplicationMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Application>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Application> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("Application");
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id);
        mapping.Map(x => x.FriendlyName);
        mapping.Join("AppCategory", x => x.Map(y => y.AppCategory));
    }
}
```

**Mapping XML (pulled from Fluent NHibernate log message):**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">

    <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true"
        name="MyApp.Domain.Entities.Application, MyApp.Domain, Version=1.0.0.76, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="Application">

        <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="Id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <property name="FriendlyName" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <column name="FriendlyName" />
        </property>

        <join table="AppCategory">
            <key>
                <column name="ApplicationId" />
            </key>
            <property name="AppCategory" type="MyApp.Domain.Entities.AppCategory, MyApp.Domain, Version=1.0.0.76, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
                <column name="AppCategory" />
            </property>
        </join>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe it is too late, but you will still be interested in the solution that I've found. I've faced the same problem when I was trying to override mappings for one of my entities.

The typical reason for this error is when you are trying to call `Map()` for the complex type. In this case Fluent NHibernate is trying to figure out the type of this entity to map to corresponding database type (e.g. `int` to `integer`, `bool` to `bit`, etc) and as far as there is no such correspondence for the `AppCategory` type it fails.

So your error will probably be fixed if you'll change following line

```
 mapping.Join("AppCategory", x => x.Map(y => y.AppCategory));
```

to this one

```
 mapping.Join("AppCategory", x => x.References(y => y.AppCategory));
```

Comment: This is the exact cause. Thanks for chiming in with the correct solution.